# How to get pictures from mounted volume in java spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar

I have a java application in a docker container and saving pictures is working fine but getting them doesnt work I get Error: javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!.

this is my doker image,

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=*.jar
EXPOSE 9000
COPY  build/libs/wall-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar .
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","wall-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

The mounting part is being done in the kubernetes cluster configuration:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wall-app
  labels:
    app: wall-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: wall-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wall-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: wall-app
        image: u/wall
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9010
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 512Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: images-volume
          mountPath: /images
      volumes:
      - name: images-volume
        hostPath:
          path: /home/ubuntu/images-volume
```

My java application function to get image:
Not: Im sure that the pic name is corret the probelm is with the input stream

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/post/image")
    public @ResponseBody String getImageAsBase64(@RequestBody String json){

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            String path = "/images/post/" + jsonObject.get("postId) + "/" +      jsonObject.get("pictureName");

            InputStream in = getClass()
                    .getResourceAsStream(path);

            String encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(IOUtils.toByteArray(in));

           System.out.print(path);
           //images/post/5/test.png

            return encodedString;
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("picture not found"+e);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

[image: This files inside the container were you can see the mounted volume"images"]

I tried ../ to get one directory above but it did not work

Comment: `kubectl exec -it my-pod -- /bin/bash` into your pod and check if the files are where you expect them to be.

Comment: Also there is a missing quote in `jsonObject.get("postId) + "/" +` after `postId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `getResourceAsStream` method is only to be used for reading resources (files) from the classpath, which is a rather logical thing. As far as I can see, you want to read the images directly from the file system, outside of your classpath as can be observed from your `ENTRYPOINT`. For that, you can use `FileInputStream`. So, you have to replace the `in` variable with the following code:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(path);
```

But don't forget about closing the input stream. You can use the convenient [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for that purpose. After that, your relevant piece of code will look like this:

```
try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(path)) {

    String encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(IOUtils.toByteArray(in));

    System.out.print(path);
    //images/post/5/test.png

    return encodedString;
}
```